# GWT Textfield with content assist kind of functionality

Tags: gwt

I am working on a project and I have a requirement to create one GWT Textfield. User should be able to put query in the text field. But this text field should have content assist (like Ecliplse) kind of functionality.

Example: "path" is one of the predefined object in the application with having certain attribute like "name","address". So now when user type "path.", it should show available attribute. This should work almost same way as in eclipse we get while put objectname it will give all available methods to call.

Example: User writes text "From path.name, path.attribute for object.attribute"
When user writes "from","for" it will not show any assistance but when user types "path." or "object." in above statement, it should show assist.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting idea. You could try this with a suggest box widget.

GWT Suggest Box - http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSuggestBox

GWTChosen Suggest Box - http://jdramaix.github.com/gwtchosen/

The above widget demos work with simple "contains" check on string. You would need to spend some serious logic on the regex matching if you want to pull of your idea.